# Marketing Cloud - IP Addresses Warming

Tags: marketing-cloud, documentation, ip-warming

I'm trying to Warm Up one IP, in [Marketing Cloud docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_ip_address_warming.htm&type=5) I see the "IP Addresses Warming Recommendation" Table

[image]

But It's not so clear if the Sends in this table is:

1) Total amount in the period. For example, to Microsoft in Day 1 send 5,000, then more 7,500 in Day 2 and more 7,500 in Day 3.

2) The total value for each day in all. For example, to Microsoft Sends 20,000 every Day.

Also, if in Microsoft includes hotmail.com, outlook.com, live.com all together or for each one of those domains is a "separated warm up".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recommendation from this table is per send - and it is recommended to have 3 sends per week, doubling the volume week on week.

However, I have seen several issues with ISPs (e.g. Hotmail) which will have me recommend not starting with higher volumes than 5.000 emails per ISP for each of the sends on week 1. The capping is in many cases far lower than 20.000 emails/day.

There is more on this topic in my answer here: [IP warm-up strategy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252220/ip-warm-up-strategy/252339#252339)

Comment: Thank you @Lukas
So you would recommend me to start (Microsoft) with 5.000 sends, 3x in the first week? (monitoring these sends and reduce if some delivery issues happen)

Comment: @Leto - depending on your list size, list composition (number of large vs small ISPs) I will recommend taking 5000 of the most engaged subscribers from all MS domains (Hotmail, Live, Outlook), 5000 from Gmail, etc. until you have 30-50.000 subscribers. You can have 3 different lists, one for each day of the week.